# /.well-known/assetlinks.json is not updating after adding sha256 fingerprint

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have created dedicated site for dynamic links, added url prefix and looks like firebase released that site automatically. After creating url prefix I have noticed that I missed sha256 fingerprint, went ahead and added it.
Now /.well-known/assetlinks.json is not updating, new release isn't being made. What can I do to force it to release updated version with proper assetlinks.json file?

I would expect that firebase make a new release when sha256 fingerprint is added...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it takes longer than expected, after a couple of hours it finally got updated.